# Улучшение кода в таймере обратного отсчёта в java андроид

Tags: java, android

Имеется таймер обратного отсчета, который через промежуток времени 6, 7, 8 секунд от начала отсчёта меняет цвет `TextViewer`, реализовано это проверкой с использованием операторов `if`, количество проверок зависит от величины поля `inTimeVydox`, значение которого делиться на семь и получаем количество семерок-поле `inKolichestoSemerok`.

При `inKolichestoSemerok=1`, выполняется три проверки с использованием `if`, если `inKolichestoSemerok=2`, то выполняется шесть проверок.
А всего в коде уже девять записей проверок с `if`! 
При `inKolichestoSemerok=3` проверять надо 9 значений.В коде будет `3+6+9=18` записей и т. д..Всё бы ничего, но значение `inTimeVydox` может быть от 1 до 120.

С увеличение полей `inTimeVydox` и `inKolichestoSemerok` увеличивается объём кода.

**Вопрос:** Как можно уменьшить количество применяемых операторов if, без вреда работоспособности кода?

```
 myCountDownTimerVydox = new CountDownTimer(inTimevydox * 1000, MILLIS_PER_SECOND) {

            @Override
            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinishedVydox) {

                long sekUntilFinishedVydox = millisUntilFinishedVydox / 1000;

                if (inKolichestoSemerok == 1)
                {
                    if (sekUntilFinishedVydox == inTimevydox - 6) {
                        textview_vremyVydox.setBackgroundResource(R.color.redColor);
                    }
                    if (sekUntilFinishedVydox == inTimevydox - 7) {
                        textview_vremyVydox.setBackgroundResource(R.color.colorblue);

                    }
                    if (sekUntilFinishedVydox == inTimevydox - 8) {
                        textview_vremyVydox.setBackgroundResource(R.color.Teal);

                    }
                }
                if (inKolichestoSemerok == 2)
                {
                    if (sekUntilFinishedVydox == inTimevydox - 6) {
                        textview_vremyVydox.setBackgroundResource(R.color.redColor);
                    }
                    if (sekUntilFinishedVydox == inTimevydox - 7) {
                        textview_vremyVydox.setBackgroundResource(R.color.colorblue);
                    }
                    if (sekUntilFinishedVydox == inTimevydox - 8) {
                        textview_vremyVydox.setBackgroundResource(R.color.Teal);
                    }
                    if (sekUntilFinishedVydox == inTimevydox - 13) {
                        textview_vremyVydox.setBackgroundResource(R.color.redColor);
                    }
                    if (sekUntilFinishedVydox == inTimevydox - 14) {
                        textview_vremyVydox.setBackgroundResource(R.color.colorblue);
                    }
                    if (sekUntilFinishedVydox == inTimevydox - 15) {
                        textview_vremyVydox.setBackgroundResource(R.color.Teal);

                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: индусы тихо завидуют вашему коду.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Как можно уменьшить количество применяемых операторов if, без вреда
>   работоспособности кода?

1. Оптимизировать код, приведя логику, так сказать, к общему знаменателю.
2. Вообще избавиться от `if`, заменив на `switch` при множестве условий.

Answer (score 3):

Попробуйте так

```
@Override
public void onTick(long millisUntilFinishedVydox) {

    long sekUntilFinishedVydox = millisUntilFinishedVydox / 1000;
    int inKolichestoSemerok = inTimevydox/7;

    if (sekUntilFinishedVydox == inTimevydox - (inKolichestoSemerok*7 - 1)) {
        textview_vremyVydox.setBackgroundResource(R.color.redColor);
    }
    if (sekUntilFinishedVydox == inTimevydox - (inKolichestoSemerok*7)) {
        textview_vremyVydox.setBackgroundResource(R.color.colorblue);
    }
    if (sekUntilFinishedVydox == inTimevydox - (inKolichestoSemerok*7 + 1)) {
        textview_vremyVydox.setBackgroundResource(R.color.Teal);
    }
}
```